# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #1](https://ham.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Amateur Radio has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new pro-temp moderators are:

[image: David Hoelzer]

[image: rclocher3]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://ham.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://ham.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4826213735464960).