# Congratulations to us—ham.SE is no longer a beta site!

Tags: discussion, beta, moderators, election

As of today, 16 December 2021, ham.stackexchange.com is no longer a beta StackExchange site!  We graduated along with 57 other sites.  Congratulations are in order!  Here's the [official announcement](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/16/congratulations-are-in-order-these-sites-are-leaving-beta/).

The day-to-day working of the site shouldn't be any different.  Our graduation may lead to minor changes in the future; I've seen rumblings that graduated sites might eventually get their own logos.  (This might be an opportunity for anyone who would like to design a free logo for the site.  Our users would probably choose a logo by ballot from a short list of choices.)

Oh, apparently there may be another moderator election sometime between February and April 2022, because three of our five moderators were appointed.  (The other two were elected in a [special election](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/456/2021-community-moderator-election-results).)  Non-beta sites have elected moderators.

Comment: Nice! Yes, the only difference I see is the " - Beta" is missing at the top of the main page.

Comment: I don't have the reps to edit, but it says "16 September 2021"...

Comment: I changed the date in the text to December

Comment: So, should suggestions for a different logo (if any) be in answers here, or should we have a separate meta post? In any case, I think that's going to be tricky for this site, since it will have to be small. [Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/) has the top of a Phillips head screw as theirs. That really limits things. You couldn't put a transceiver in a logo. But maybe a bandswitch with band numbers 80-40-20. Or should we just keep the present *AR* logo?

Comment: If the title were edited, this page might be used for a discussion on logos and a separate graphic  on the site pages. The latter might be a transceiver or even a ham station.

Comment: We could do it that way @MikeWaters, but I think I'd favor a separate discussion about logos and graphics.  BTW I favor something that looks similar to the ARRL logo: a schematic representation of an earth ground in series with an inductor and an antenna.